# Determine depth of node in full/perfect post-order binary tree

Tags: logic, graph-theory, first-order-logic, binary-operations

How can I determine the depth of a node in a perfect/full binary tree(each node has either 2 or 0 leafs). The nodes are labeled by a post-order traversal of the tree. For example, in this tree:

```
Depth = 4
//         15                    
//    7         14                   
//  3   6    10   13              
// 1 2 4 5  8 9  11 12
```

I would like to find the depth of a single node, given the total depth of the tree. The depth of each left most leaf is `log(n+1)/log(2)`, but I don't know how to find an inner node's depth.

PS: My goal is to find the parent of each node and the parent of each right node is `n+1` and the coresponding right node to a left one is `n+(2^depth)-1`. So I figure knowing the depth would be enough to find the parent.

Comment: So is the question to find the depth of the node as a function of its label in the post-order traversal?

Comment: The question was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20457938/1866458) with a very good explanation and example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the vertices of the full binary tree of height $h$ are numbered by $1, 2, \ldots, 2^h - 1$ in post-order, then you can recover the depth of a node (i.e., its distance from the root) by the following recursive formula:

$$
\operatorname{d}(k, h) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } k = 2^h - 1 \\
1 + \operatorname{d}\Big(k - (2^{h-1}-1)\cdot k_{h-1}, h-1\Big) & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

where $k_{i}$ is the $i$'th digit in the binary expansion of $k$, that is, $$6_0 = 0, 6_1 = 1, 6_2 = 1, 6_3 = 0, 6_4 = 0, \ldots$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$